# Why would a simple "SELECT FROM _" actually find a smaller number of rows than a "SELECT FROM _ WHERE _ "

Tags: sql

The question seems ridiculous but I'm struggling finding the basic docs that could answer it.

I am looking at a datatable which apparently contains 258706 rows. That's what I get from:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `my_table`
```

258706

When I specify a condition I actually get all these rows. For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `id` < 1000000
```

returns 258706 rows.

However, if I remove the WHERE condition, some rows disappear:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table`
```

returns only 249627 rows.

If I look at the structure of the table, I see that the cardinality of the primary key is only  249627. So I guess the first statement only keep those with a distinct id value while the second one keeps everything... but why is that so?

And more generally, how could the cardinality of a not null primary key (that should be unique by definition, right?) not be equal to the number of rows?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here is the index (I'm not responsible for the design)

Nom de l'index  Type    Unique  Compressé   Colonne Cardinalité Interclassement Null

PRIMARY BTREE   Oui Non id  249627  A   Non

id  BTREE   Oui Non id  249627  A   Non

old_eid BTREE   Oui Non old_eid 39011   A   Oui

id_activite BTREE   Oui Non id_activite 185560  A   Oui

id_location 157663  A   Oui

num_event   249627  A   Non

begin   BTREE   Non Non begin   55200   A   Oui

end BTREE   Non Non end 60870   A   Oui

Comment: "returns 258706 rows..." -- did you actually count them? Database drivers are notorious at returning *estimated number of rows* instead of actual ones. Please count them.

Comment: If I export them as a csv I actually have 258706 rows

Comment: Did you export both queries to count them or just one of them?

Comment: You're right, both exports have actually 258706 rows! thanks! But why would one approximation from the driver would be correct and the other wrong?

Comment: Because drivers and database engines are **lazy**. I learned a long time those numbers are just estimates. It actually says it somewhere in the documentation. The database engines are trying to do the less amount of work all the time, in order to serve more simultaneous users.

Comment: Thanks! I'll remember not to trust them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify your database.  One possibility (rather remote) is that your database is doing an approximation for `count(*)`.  More likely, the data changed -- some rows were deleted.

The cardinality of a primary key is the size of the table.  A primary key has unique values and is never `NULL`.  These conditions are enforced by the database.

Note that some operations may use an approximation of the database size.  So if you are reading the table size from an explain plan, for instance, that might only be approximate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However the database is local and fixed - I can execute the statements again and again and always get the same results.

Comment: Actually you're right, the problem was the approximation from the database driver. I still wonder why it guesses right with one syntax and not with the other one...